# AWS ECS how to launch containers in private bridge network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

How do I get docker automatic service discovery working in an AWS ECS EC2 based cluster service?

I have this corresponding `docker-compose.yml` (which I'm mapping over to a ECS compatible `task-definition.json` file):

```
version: "3"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.2
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.0.12
  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.3
  api:
    image: api
    build: .
    command: api.py
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - mongo
      - redis
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

If I launch this with `docker-compose up` docker-composer will create a new private bridge network. Within this private network "automatic service discovery" is on and service names resolve to service IP addresses. So for example the *api* can find *mongo* without knowing its IP by doing a DNS lookup for "mongo". The network is also isolated from other unrelated containers. You can do this manually via `docker` too like this:

```
docker network create api-net
docker run -d --name elasticsearch --net api-net docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.2
docker run -d --name mongo --net api-net mongo:4.0.12
...
```

But I can't figure out how I can achieve the same via AWS ECS multi-container service defined with a `task-definition.json` file. If I define multiple services with "bridge" networking all containers are launched into the default bridge network and automatic service discovery does not work. I can manually log into the ECS EC2 container instance and set up a private network, but obviously not a workable solution.

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope not yet. The one answer here suggests (but doesn't provide good enough background to be 100%) that you can't get out of the default bridge NW in ECS :/.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use :

```
"links": ["name:internalName", ...]
```

see more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_network) under `Network Settings`

please see this note also:

> Important
>
> Containers that are collocated on a single container instance may be
>   able to communicate with each other without requiring links or host
>   port mappings. Network isolation is achieved on the container instance
>   using security groups and VPC settings.

Comment: Just tested. DNS is working somehow but ECS is definitely not creating a new private docker network. Do you know if it that is possible. It would avoid the "Important" note issue I think.

Comment: just search for "Network Mode" in the link I added above I am not really sure if that possible , can't see anything on private networks. but why you need them ?

Comment: Isolation is the main reason. I guess I can live with just DNS.

Comment: as in the notes :  `Network isolation is achieved on the container instance using security groups and VPC settings.`

Comment: Yes but it sounds much more complicated the doing it through docker. I'll have to give it a try.

Comment: Why would this need links if they're not necessary in docker-compose? By default ECS creates a "`bridge` — The task utilizes Docker's built-in virtual network which runs inside each Amazon EC2 instance hosting the task." However I've specified hostnames for my containers (using CDK) and still cannot get inter-container networking to work.

Comment: @MartynasJusevičius "Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses, unless you use the --link option, which is considered legacy. On a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve each other by name or alias." - https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/